# Make an Angular module only load in component

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I have an Angular application with SSR (Angular Universal) and I know that everthing related to browser, like `window`, `document`, `setTimeout`... Are not supported by SSR, so I rewrite all of my code to match these criterias and only load browser specific content after confirmation that application is running on a browser.

```js
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

isBrowser: boolean;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) {
  this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
}

loadLocalstorage(): void {
  if (this.isBrowser) {...logic here}
}
```

Question is. I use a library called `ng-apexcharts` which are not compatible with SSR, so I need to load it after `isBrowser` confirmation. The problem is this library are loaded by a module `NgApexchartsModule` and I don't know how I can load a module after that confirmation, because I can't inject `PLATFORM_ID` into my module that have the component using `ngApexcharts`.

Is there a way to load a module on component? It can be whatever hierarchy necessary, but I need to make that verification before load it's module.

Probably lazy loading will not be the answer, because I don't want to change route, I just want to load `NgApexchartsModule` when application confirm that is in a browser